# Spark explode a dataframe array of structs based on index from another element from array

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I currently have a dataframe:

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- location: string (nullable = true)
 |-- polls: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- variable_values: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- RatingOne: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- RatingTwo: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- RatingThree: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- RatingFour: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- RatingFive: string (nullable = true)
```

Here is an example table with data:

```
  name | location | polls   
 ----------------------------
 John  | Atlanta  | [0,[null, 9, null, null, null], 1,[6, null, null, null, null]]
 Henry | Arizona  | [0,[null, null, 7, null, null], 1,[null, null, null, 10, null]]
```

How do I transform the above dataframe to the one below?

```
  name | location | polls_key | polls_rating   
 ----------------------------
 John  | Atlanta  | 0         | 9
 John  | Atlanta  | 1         | 6
 Henry | Arizona  | 0         | 7
 Henry | Arizona  | 1         | 10
```

After using explode I got duplicate data

```
  name | location | polls_key | polls_rating   
 ----------------------------
 John  | Atlanta  | 0         | 9
 John  | Atlanta  | 0         | 6
 John  | Atlanta  | 1         | 9
 John  | Atlanta  | 1         | 6
 Henry | Arizona  | 0         | 7
 Henry | Arizona  | 0         | 10
 Henry | Arizona  | 1         | 7
 Henry | Arizona  | 1         | 10
```

Comment: Your actual output doesn't make sense. Could you share your code please?

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be only one non null value per `variable_values`. In that case, you can use `explode` and then `coalesce` as follows:

```scala
val exploded_df = df
    .select('name, 'location, explode('polls) as "poll")
    .select('name, 'location, $"poll.key" as "polls_key", $"poll.variable_values.*")

// getting the list of rating columns
val rating_cols = exploded_df.columns.filter(_ startsWith "Rating")

exploded_df
    .withColumn("polls_rating", coalesce(rating_cols.map(col _) : _*))
    .drop(rating_cols : _*)
    .show
```

```
+-----+--------+---------+------------+
| name|location|polls_key|polls_rating|
+-----+--------+---------+------------+
| John| Atlanta|        0|           9|
| John| Atlanta|        1|           6|
|Henry| Arizona|        0|           7|
|Henry| Arizona|        1|          10|
+-----+--------+---------+------------+
```